# Want to display page only if

Tags: javascript

simple question.. or maybe not.

I would like to display my page only if condition below is true, till now i have to reload page a few times to makes it happen (ie. makes contition true)

Thank you for the help!

```js
const min = 1.01;
const max = 5.5;
const rate1 = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
const rate2 = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
const rate3 = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);

console.log(rate1, rate2, rate3);

if (rate1 < rate2 && rate2 < rate3 && rate1 < rate3) {
  // only if that condition is true, display the page.
  console.log("The condition was true");
}
```

Comment: why to reload page? Just do ot in loop until you will get proper results

Comment: what do you mean by display page? redirect to a url or show content on the current web page

Comment: just an insight: if x < y and y < z, then x < z is also true. in other words, your `if` can be simplified.

Comment: How about using something like `var RatesAreWrong = true; while( RatesAreWrong ) { GenerateNewRates(); RatesAreWrong = /*...*/ } DisplayPage();`

Comment: instead, show loader image..

Comment: incase you didn't know, you could just do `document.getElementByTagName("body").style.display = "none"` to hide the webpage, and you can replace `none` with `block` to display the page

Comment: if true;  send ajax; ajax result document.write()

Comment: Someone add that kind of solution ```if (rate1 < rate2 && rate2 < rate3 && rate1 < rate3) {
      // only if that condition is true, display the page.
      console.log(rate1);
      console.log(rate2);
      console.log(rate3);
    }
   else{location.reload(); }``` is it good way to resolve this problem or can we find better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a while loop, when your condition is met show the content.

```js
const min = 1.01;
const max = 5.5;
let rates = [0, 0, 0];
while (!(rates[0] < rates[1] && rates[1] < rates[2])) {
  rates = rates.map(x => x = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2))
}
console.log(rates);
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
```

```html
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
  my content
</div>
```